# Groupby, apply custom function to data, return results in new columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to group by `id`, apply a custom function to the data, and create a new column with the results. It seems there must be a faster/more efficient way to do this than to pass the data to the function, make the changes, and return the data. Here is an example.

**Example**

```
dat = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'], 'x': [4, 8, 12, 25, 30, 50]})

def my_func(data):
    data['diff'] = (data['x'] - data['x'].shift(1, fill_value=data['x'].iat[0]))
    return data

dat.groupby('id').apply(my_func)
```

**Output**

```
id  x   diff
0   a   4   0
1   a   8   4
2   a   12  4
3   b   25  0
4   b   30  5
5   b   50  20
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I tried a few variations on your code. I was surprised at how performant the groupby approach really was!

I changed your test data to use more values -- this amortizes the overhead a bit more. Surprisingly, the overhead is a lot of the difference. When I pushed the array length too high, the differences got very small for the groupby-based alternatives.

That said, there are some things you can do to speed things up:

```
original:        18.022180362
org_prefill:     14.969489811999996
unique_keys:     23.526526202000007
groupby_return:  15.557421341999998
groupby_prefill: 15.846651952999991
shifty:           9.605120361000004
```

I tried moving away from `groupby` by iterating over the distinct key values, but that didn't pay off: the performance got worse (`unique_keys`). I tried playing games with the return value from groupby, hoping to eliminate some duplicated effort. I eventually got that in `groupby_return`. For small sizes, where the overhead is more of a factor, I got a tiny speed boost by pre-filling the result column before running the groupby. That's `groupby_prefill` and then `org_prefill` where I back-ported it. You can see that it pays off versus the original code, but not against the `groupby_return` code.

Finally, I eliminated the groupby entirely, by figuring out how to detect the start of a group using `.shift()`. Then I computed a shifted-by-one series and did the subtract operation as a single expression. That's `shifty` and it's the most performant by a bunch. W00t!

```
import sys
import timeit

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def make_df():
    n = 10_000
    df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a']*(n//2) + ['b']*(n//2),
                    'x': np.random.randn(n)})
    return df

def original(df):
    def my_func(group):
        group['diff'] = (group['x'] - group['x'].shift(
            1, fill_value=group['x'].iat[0]))
        return group

    df.groupby('id').apply(my_func)

def org_prefill(df):
    def my_func(group):
        group['diff'] = (group['x'] - group['x'].shift(
            1, fill_value=group['x'].iat[0]))
        return group

    df['diff'] = df['x']
    df.groupby('id').apply(my_func)

def unique_keys(df):
    #print("DF:\n", df)
    df['diff'] = 0
    for key in df.id.unique():
        matches = (df.id == key)
        #df.loc[matches, 'diff'] = df.loc[matches, 'x'] - df.loc[matches, 'x'].shift(1, fill_value=df.loc[matches, 'x'].iat[0])
        df_lmx = df.loc[matches, 'x']
        df.loc[matches, 'diff'] = df_lmx - df_lmx.shift(1, fill_value=df_lmx.iat[0])

def groupby_iter(df):
    for key, subset in df.groupby('id'):
        subset['diff'] = subset.x - subset.x.shift(1,
                fill_value=subset.x.iat[0])

def groupby_return(df):
    def my_func2(group):
        gx = group['x']
        result = gx - gx.shift(1, fill_value=gx.iat[0])
        return result

    res = df.groupby('id').apply(my_func2)
    df['diff'] = res.values

def groupby_prefill(df):
    def my_func2(group):
        gx = group['x']
        result = gx - gx.shift(1, fill_value=gx.iat[0])
        return result

    df['diff'] = df['x']
    res = df.groupby('id').apply(my_func2)
    df['diff'] = res.values

def shifty(df):
    shifted = df['x'].shift(fill_value=df['x'].iat[0])
    shifted.loc[(df.id != df.id.shift())] = df['x']
    df['diff'] = df['x'] - shifted

if __name__ == '__main__':
    kwargs = {
        'globals': globals(),
        'number': 1000,
        'setup': 'df = make_df()',
    }

    print("original:", timeit.timeit('original(df)', **kwargs))
    print("org_prefill:", timeit.timeit('org_prefill(df)', **kwargs))

    print("unique_keys:", timeit.timeit('unique_keys(df)', **kwargs))
    #print("groupby_iter:", timeit.timeit('groupby_iter(df)', **kwargs))
    print("groupby_return:", timeit.timeit('groupby_return(df)', **kwargs))
    print("groupby_prefill:", timeit.timeit('groupby_prefill(df)', **kwargs))
    print("shifty:", timeit.timeit('shifty(df)', **kwargs))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to try [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/). Turn the DataFrame columns into Numpy arrays. Although, I couldn't get it working with letters, here it is with number id's. (ran in Jupyter)

```
import sys
import timeit

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numba import jit


n = 1000

id_arr = np.concatenate((np.tile(1, n//2),  np.tile(2, n//2)), axis=None)
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': id_arr,
                'x': np.random.randn(n)})

@jit(nopython=True)
def calculator_nb(id, x):
    res = np.empty(x.shape)
    res[0] = 0
    for i in range(1, res.shape[0]):
        if id[i] == id[i-1]:
            res[i] = x[i] - x[i-1]
        else: 
            res[i] = 0

    return res

%timeit calculator_nb(*df[['id', 'x']].values.T)
459 µs ± 1.85 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```